# Using Formula to determine Shift from Time data (Excel)

Tags: excel, datetime, if-statement, excel-formula, data-analysis

I have a column of time data formatted like this: [Machine_Usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R08vz.png)

I want to make an IF statement that returns 1, 2 or 3 corresponding to first, second or third shift if the times fall between certain values.

I already tried many times but not worked, please help me.

I want to find the right formula/syntax that can solved this problem for length of use of the machine based on the shift.

Comment: You have some start and end date-time that do not correspond to the same day, for example the third row. The shift you have are related to the same day. Is that an error in your data or do you need to handle this in a specific way? Please clarify

Comment: Your third shift is defined to have an end time that is earlier than its start.  You could say third shift is 22 to 30 hours, but then if a machine started at 1:00 and ended at 4:00 it would not be in any of those.  Also, your first example runs during all 3 shifts.  Should your function return 123?

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible approach, but *not an answer* because the question needs clarification on how to handle the following situations:

- The interval [`Start`, `End`] is not within a single shift. According to some input data, it starts in one shift and ends in another one.
- When `End` corresponds to a day after `Start`. This only can apply for shift `3`, but based on the data there is no such scenario

In cell `F2` put the following formula (the result is spilled, no need to drag down the formula)

```
=LET(start, C2:C20, end, D2:D20, lkup, H2:J4, shift, INDEX(lkup,,1),
  lkStart, INDEX(lkup,,2), lkEnd, INDEX(lkup,,3),
  MAP(start, end, LAMBDA(ss,ee, LET(startI, INT(ss) + lkStart, 
    endI, INT(ss) + lkEnd,
    result, FILTER(shift, (ss >= startI) * (ee < endI), "Shift not found"),
    IF(ROWS(result) > 1, "Overlap", result)
  )))
)
```

Here is the output:

[image: sample excel file]

As you can see based on the data issue mentioned before no shift was found for any of the rows. Probably after data clean-up or more clarification, the formula should return a more realistic result.

Even the Shift information is represented in `hh:mm` format (see the previous screenshot). The end date of the last shift corresponds to the next day. Therefore the numeric values associated with the hours are the following:

```
Shift   Start   End
1       0.25    0.58
2       0.58    0.92
3       0.92    1.25
```

The logic of the formula is based on the above settings.